# Finding set of complex numbers from condition $\{ z : |z^2 - 1 | \leq 1 \}.$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having some issues

> Finding the set of complex numbers $z$ such that
>   $$\left \{ z : \left |z^2 - 1 \right | \leq 1 \right \}.$$

My first attempt was to rewrite the condition as

$$ \left |z^2 - 1 \right | = \left |(z - 1)(z + 1) \right | = |z+1||z-1|. $$
By defining $z = x + iy$, I then get 
$$ |z+1||z-1| = \sqrt{\left \{(x + 1)^2 + y^2 \right \} \left \{ (x - 1)^2 + y^2 \right \}} \leq 1.$$
Evaluating the above expression, I find that it cannot be entirely imaginary, however it can be entirely real between $-\sqrt{2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{2}$. However, I'm not entirely certain regarding the area separate from the two axes. Would be grateful for any tips on how to proceed (or point out where I'm going wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ where $x,y \in \Bbb R$. Then:

$$\begin{array}{lrcl}
& |z^2-1| &\le& 1 \\
\iff & |(x+iy)^2-1| &\le& 1 \\
\iff & |(x^2-y^2-1)+i(2xy)| &\le& 1 \\
\iff & (x^2-y^2-1)^2+(2xy)^2 &\le& 1 \\
\iff & (x^2+y^2)^2-2(x^2-y^2)+1 &\le& 1 \\
\iff & (x^2+y^2)^2+2(x^2+y^2)+1-4x^2 &\le& 1 \\
\iff & (x^2+y^2+1)^2-4x^2 &\le& 1 \\
\iff & (x^2+y^2+1+2x)(x^2+y^2+1-2x) &\le& 1 \\
\iff & ((x+1)^2+y^2)((x-1)^2+y^2) &\le& 1 \\
\end{array}$$

A geometric interpretation is that the product of the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(1,0)$ and the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(-1,0)$ is less than or equal to $1$.

See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aphu85tyke) for a sketch of the graph.

Answer (score 3):

Setting $z=x+iy$, the inequation with modulus is equivalent to
$$(z^2-1)(\bar z^2-1) \le 1 \iff(x^2+y^2)^2\le 2(x^2-y^2).$$

Now the curve with equation $\;(x^2+y^2)^2= 2(x^2-y^2)$ is the well-known *lemniscate of Bernoulli* (which has the shape of the $\infty$ symbol). For topological reasons, the set of solutions of the inequation is the union of the lemniscate and its interior.

Answer (score 2):

All I can show is following:

Say $$M = \{z\in \mathbb{C}; |z^2-1|\leq 1\}$$ and $$N = \{z\in \mathbb{C}; |z|\leq \sqrt{2}\}.$$

By triangle inequality we have $$|z^2|-1\leq |z^2-1|\leq 1 \Rightarrow |z|^2\leq 2$$

so if $z\in M$ then $z\in N$ and thus $M\subseteq N$ (and $N$ is circle with radius $\sqrt{2}$).

Yet $M\ne N$ since $i\sqrt{2}\in N$ and it is not in $M$.

Comment: Any way, I draw it in Geogebra and I got $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

with $$z=x+iy$$ we get $$\sqrt{(x^2-y^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2}\le 1$$ this is equivalent to$$((x+1)^2+y^2)((x-1)^2+y^2)\le 1$$

Comment: no, $$(x^2-y^2)^2+4x^2y^2=x^4+y^4-2x^2y^2+4x^2y^2=x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2=...$$

Comment: yes just corrected